# A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'SigninCharacter'

Tags: flutter, error-handling, dart-null-safety

I'm making a radio button then i face this error.//A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'SigninCharacter'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'SigninCharacter'.\

```
enum SigninCharacter { fill, outline }

class productOverVeiw extends StatefulWidget {
  const productOverVeiw({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<productOverVeiw> createState() => _productOverVeiwState();
}

class _productOverVeiwState extends State<productOverVeiw> {
  SigninCharacter _character = SigninCharacter.fill;


Radio(
                                  value: SigninCharacter.fill,
                                  groupValue: _character,
                                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _character = value ;//A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'SigninCharacter'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'SigninCharacter'.\
                                    });
                                  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this just add the value type SigninCharacter to value:

```
Radio(
              value: SigninCharacter.fill,
              groupValue: _character,
              activeColor: Colors.green,
              onChanged: (SigninCharacter? value) {  // <--- assign it here
                setState(() {
                  _character = value!; // and add ! to value
                });
              })
```

Comment: yes this is the rigtht answer